# Does taking Vitmain B-Complex with zinc through tablets really help in reversing hair fall

Tags: nutrition, dermatology, micronutrients

I am thinking of taking Vitmain B-Complex tablets. I am concerned about my overall metabolism and my prime concern is my hairs. Does it also help in treating premature grey hairs?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! As a member of other SE sites, you're probably aware that good questions *invite* explanation. Providing background from reading that you've done helps make your question better. Also, SE asks that you ask only one (reasonable scope allowed) question at a time. Again, welcome.

Comment: Not unless you have vitamin B deficiency.

Comment: Not sure about grey hair, but with some antibiotics, vitamin B complex is given in order to keep away from any deficiency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an expert answer for your question. May be this will help you to take right decision.

[NDTV Doctors:](http://doctor.ndtv.com/faq/ndtv/fid/2322/Is_a_combination_of_B-complex_vitamin_and_zinc_good_for_the_hair.html)

> "There is no harm in taking a combination of B-complex vitamins with
>   zinc but there is no evidence that such products have any utility in
>   controlling loss of hair. Please do not rely on reports in the lay
>   press because they are not always correct. Sometimes such reports are
>   sponsored by manufacturers. There is some evidence that anti-oxidant
>   preparations (such as Vitexid) may help in improving general well
>   being of most body functions including skin of the scalp. I hope you
>   are not suffering from dandruff which is a common cause of hair loss."

Comment: Thank you for your post, I edited your post a little bit for readability. If you dislike the changes feel free to go to the editing history and rollback. Thank you!